# SSIS: data mining query in the control flow vs data flow

Tags: ssis

Why would you choose one over the other? Is there a (major) difference between the two?

Answer (score 0):

BOL page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403377%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) gives the best answer to this.